# Second plot's label doesn't shown using artist layer of matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-science, visualization

I want to create two charts. One is boxplot and second is line plot.
I've tried to give them individual labels but line plot's top label is not shown.

**Code that I tried:**

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax0 = fig.add_subplot(1,2,1)
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,2,2)

new_df.iloc[:,0:3].plot(
    kind='box',
    figsize=(20,7),
    color='red',
    ax=ax0
)

ax0.set_title('Boxdiagramm für Ländern')
ax0.set_ylabel('Nummern')
ax0.set_xlabel('Jahre')

new_df['Total'].plot(
    kind='line',
    figsize=(20,7),
    ax=ax1
)

ax1.set_label('Linediagramm für Ländern')
ax1.set_ylabel('Nummern')
ax1.set_xlabel('Ländern')
ax1.legend(labels=None)

plt.show()
```

**Output of the code:**

[image: Output image link]

How can I add the second plot's label?

Comment: Try adding `label="label text"` as parameter to the plot method and a legend to the first plot.

Comment: Do you mean the axes *title*? Because you never have `ax1.set_title(...)`?

Comment: @BigBen oh... This could be it Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of using `ax1.set_label('Linediagramm für Ländern')`, you should use `ax1.set_title('Linediagramm für Ländern')`.